# securely storing login details to external services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, authentication

I’m making an app that performs tasks on other sites for you.

Example - my app would login in to your theguardian.com account and check if you have any replies to your comments and perform an action if you do.

I'm wondering how I should store, and read, the login details for the guardian.com in my app? Obviously I want to avoid plain text.

I'm using rails and Postgres, my app is fully SSL.

**EDIT:**

I'm voting to close the question as it's obviously a bad idea and it  looks like people are going to tell me so many times. @jvillian has suggested a gem which will help encrypt properties on a model if I do want to avoid plain text, which may be of use to anyone who stumbles across the question.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to store your users' credentials to third party websites, not your own login details? Why do you think users will give you this details?

Comment: @spickermann correct, I want to store their credentials to other sites. "Why do I think they would give them to me?" -> I'm not sure, I probably wouldn't give mine away. If I can explain that I store them in the most secure way possible it *may* help win their trust.

Comment: in my opinion this is a very bad idea! to perform a login you would need to extract the clear version of the credentials at some point so you have an evident threat to the user data, consider using other means, for example many websites use oauth so you can just let the user authenticate on the target website on its own and you just store a token and keep the user session alive in a secure fashion

Answer (score 0):

Check out [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted). I haven't used it personally, but it looks like what you're looking for and looks to be an active project.